# equinumerous cartesian products proofs verification

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, cardinals

Prove that $A = (0,1) \times  (0,1)$ and $B = (2,4) \times (3, \infty)$ are equinumerous by explicitly define a bijection $h: A \rightarrow B$ Show that h is a bijection.

**What I have thus far.**

Let X = (0,1), Y = (0,1), Z = (2,4) and W = $(3, \infty)$.

There's a bijection between X and Z, such that $f(x) = 2 \cdot x +2$. therefore, we can list the sets as follows

X = {$x_1$, $x_2$,...,$x_n$}

Z = {$z_1$, $z_2$,...,$z_n$}

There's also a bijection between Y and W, such that $g(y) = tan(\frac{\pi y}{2}) + 3$ therefore, we can list the sets as follows

Y = {$y_1$, $y_2$,...,$y_m$}

W = {$w_1$, $w_2$,...,$w_m$}

Then |X x Z| = $m \cdot n$

Also |Y x W| = $m \cdot n$

Therefore we can see that |X x Z| = |Y x W|, which defines a bijection between A and B, as asked.

The question I have about this is weather or not my argument works for |Y x W| as W is an infinite set. I halfway assume it does, since there's a bijection between Y and W, but I've just started covering this material, and I'm unsure of myself at this point. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your notation conflicts (you define $f$ in two different ways). Use different letters. The sets are not finite, so the $\{q_1,... \}$ stuff makes no sense. Your functions are correct, but you are defining $f$ twice, so it is hard to write down the required bijection explicitly.

Comment: can I eliminate the list of elements above then? If these sets are infinite, isn't finding a bijection between then enough to prove their cardinality the same?

Comment: Yes. You need only show a bijection between the $A$ and $B$ (this is the definition of equinumerous.). All that you are missing is to combine the bijections which is $\phi(x,y) = (f(x),g(y))$.

Comment: h(x,y)=((2x+2),(tan(pi*y/2)+3)) completes the proof?

Comment: Yes. If $f$ is a bijection between $X$ and $Z$ and similarly for $g$, then the $\phi$ is my previous comment is a bijection between $A$ and $B$.